# Pointwise convergence and the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

**If $g_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $[0,1]$, converging pointwise to $g$, is it true that $$\int_x\frac{g_n}{1+|g_n|}\,dx\to\int_x\frac{g}{1+|g|}\,dx\;?$$**

I want to verify if my procedure is correct. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Let $g_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $[0,1]$ such that
$g_n(x)\to g(x)$ pointwise as $n\to\infty$.

Hence, it follows that $\frac{g_n}{1+|g_n|}\to\frac{g}{1+|g|}$ pointwise.

By the Dominated Convergence Theorem (since $g_n(x)$ is Lebesgue measurable and $g_n(x)\to g(x)$ exists), we must now show that $|g_n|\leq g(x)$, for each $x\in[0,1]$, assuming that there is an integrable function $g$.

So, $|\frac{g_n}{1+|g_n|}|$ = $\frac{|g_n|}{1+|g_n|}\leq\frac{g}{1+|g|}$.

Now, g is integrable as is $g_n$ for each n, s.t.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_x \frac{g_n}{1+|g_n|}\,dx=\int_x \frac{g}{1+|g|}\, dx.$$

Comment: You need to find an integrable function $f$ such that $|\frac{g_n}{1+|g_n|}|\le f$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This function could well be $\frac{g}{1+|g|}$, but you provide too little information here to verify that.

Comment: What is the best approach to go about this? I am not seeing how I need to show additional boundedness.

Comment: The answer provided shows you a way to do this in your scenario.

Comment: What is $X?\,\,$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
\Bigl|\frac{g_n}{1+|g_n|}\Bigr|\le1
$$
and the constant function $1$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.